# NodeJs handling json between http and fetchjsonp

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jsonp

My application using [fetch-jsonp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch-jsonp-es6) is failing to read JSON from a site I serve from a simple http module. I get an error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" and then a time-out error.

I'm trying out ReactJS and so put together this react component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import fetchJsonp from 'fetch-jsonp';

var data = { 'remote':{}, 'local':{} };
var fetched= false;
class FastTable extends Component {        

    loadData(url,element) {

        return fetchJsonp(url)
            .then(function(response) {                                
                return response.json(); })
            .then((responseJson) => {                                        
                data[element] = responseJson;                
                this.setState(data);
                return responseJson;
            })
            .catch((error) => {                
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    render() { 
        if (!fetched) {
            this.loadData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1','remote'); 
            this.loadData('http://localhost','local'); 
        }
        fetched=true;
        return (
            <div><pre>{JSON.stringify(data, null, 2) }</pre></div>
        );
    }
}

export default FastTable;
```

It uses the fetchJsonp to grab a JSON dataset from a test website, which works - and then from my http test site, which doesn't.

The test server has the following code:

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    var result = {
        'Bob':'Likes cheese'
    };
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    res.write(JSON.stringify(result)); 
    res.end(); 

}).listen(80);
```

I've also had mixed results reading from other JSON servers within our project.

Why is fetch-jsonp not reading from my test site? Should I be reading this data in another way?

Answer (score 0):

> More than likely, you are calling a JSON API, which does not support
>   JSONP. The difference is that JSON API responds with an object like
>   {"data": 123} and will throw the error above when being executed as a
>   function. On the other hand, JSONP will respond with a function
>   wrapped object like jsonp_123132({data: 123}).

If you want to work with JSON API try axios or supergent npm.